# Minig 0.5BTC per month with a single AntMiner S9

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, mining-software, antminer

I've used some calculators and the most I've found is mining around 0.06BTC a month. That's without electricity, internet, and cooling. How much do the major pools mine with a single S9? Can it be like 10 times more? There's a guy here saying that has a software that can make the S9 mine 0.5BTC a month. It's probably a lie, how do I catch him?

Answer (score 2):

it's not about software, it's about the capacity of your device. so a software can't add some wings to your device.

Comment: He claims it can and shows me some bitcoins that he says he earned that way. How do I catch him that he's lying?

Comment: Software can't make the ASIC faster, that's not how ASICs work.